# How can I filter incoming messages meeting certain criteria into some sort of folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

For a developer and general computer person with 10 years' familiarity with Microsoft Office but who is merely new to Outlook, you would think this would be easy, especially with Google, and yet I can not find anything even remotely related to what I want.

At my company there is a constant stream of incoming "Submit Feedback" emails for our website that for some reason CC all employees. They have a predictable body and title format, so I should be able to catch them and send them to some special folder, but I can't figure out how to do that. In fact I can't even figure out how to create the folder. Coming from 8 years (or something) of gmail, this is just not feeling even remotely intuitive.

PS I'm using a really new version of outlook but honestly I can't even figure out how to find what version it is....there's no "About" or anything like that in the menu. I'm pretty sure it's Office 2013 though.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help if you can determine which version of Outlook you are running. There are a number of ways to do this, even if you can't find the "About" screen. What does Control Panel/Programs & Features (or Add/Remove Programs) show? If you browse your Program Files directory to try to find Outlook.exe, you will find it within a folder named "Office##". Office15 corresponds to Office 2013. Which version of Microsoft Word do you have? Your Outlook version is likely the same.

Once you know your version, finding answers on Google for these simple tasks should be pretty straight-forward. In all versions of Outlook I have used, creating a new folder is as simple as right clicking on your Inbox or another folder from the folder view at the left, and click "New Folder". In outlook, these filters are called "Rules" or "Rules and Alerts". In outlook 2010, this is a "Rules" button on the home tab.

Once you get into the wizard for creating a rule, it should be straight-forward on how to set it up.